# Dynamic replace a part of a string with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to solve an issue.

I have a string that is basically HTML code:

```
let htmlTitle = "<a href="/news/sky-sport-hd-in-italia-dal-18-novembr">Sky Sport HD in italia dal 18 novembre</a> | <a href="/news/ecco-il-genio-spagnolo-designer-di-moto-elettriche">News</a> | <a href="/news/lg-electronic-e-here-insieme-per-l-auto-connessa-e-autonoma">News</a>"
```

The string comes from my DB.

I have in my vue app a "slug" input field, and inside the slug I have:

```
 "sky-sport-hd-in-italia-dal-18-novembr"
```

This is the permalink of the first content referred by the string.

When I change the input field I need that the title string adapt to my changes, and I cannot understand how can I do that.

In my title string I can have an unlimited number of anchor tags but I need to change just the `href` value that matches the slug.

I need something like this:

```
"<a href="{{ slug }}">Sky Sport HD in italia dal 18 novembre</a> | <a href="/news/ecco-il-genio-spagnolo-designer-di-moto-elettriche">News</a> | <a href="/news/lg-electronic-e-here-insieme-per-l-auto-connessa-e-autonoma">News</a>"
```

I can use a computed value but my string can be edited with a Wysiwyg editor where I can change the titles ('Sky Sport HD in italia dal 18 novembre' or 'News'). I just need to keep the slug aligned...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you need to use a computed value ([doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)).

The string htmlTitle woudl be a computed value

```
computed: {
    // ES6
    htmlTitle () {
        return `<a href="${this.slug}">Sky Sport HD in italia dal 18 novembre</a> | <a href="/news/ecco-il-genio-spagnolo-designer-di-moto-elettriche">News</a> | <a href="/news/lg-electronic-e-here-insieme-per-l-auto-connessa-e-autonoma">News</a>`
    }

    // ES5
    htmlTitle: funciton() {
        return "<a href='" + this.slug + "'>Sky Sport HD in italia dal 18 novembre</a> | <a href="/news/ecco-il-genio-spagnolo-designer-di-moto-elettriche">News</a> | <a href="/news/lg-electronic-e-here-insieme-per-l-auto-connessa-e-autonoma">News</a>"
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the question explaining why I cannot use a computed string. The titles are editable....

Answer (score 0):

Use watchers and v-html. When you change slug - just update variable with link
Here is an example

```
watch: {
  slug: function(val) {
    this.href = this.result;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1b68eLdr/52554/